# Validar si uno de los radiobutton esten seleccionados, "si" abrir pop up con otro formulario y "no", solo enviar formulario

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo este código, el cual  no se como hacer que al seleccionar el radiobutton1 me abra por pop up otro formulario, y al presionar el radiobutton2 solo que envié el formulario, solo es parte del código, lo demás lo tengo con requied y funciona perfecto, mi problema son con los radiobuttons:

Actualice el código tal y como comentan, pero sigue sin abrir el popup que se requiere, al parecer si lo valida pero al darle "SI" no abre nada, solo envía el formulario.

```
  <div class="form-group">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="radioBtn1" required="required" value="option1">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="radioBtn1">Si</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="radioBtn2" required="required"  value="option2">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="radioBtn2">No</label>
</div>

<script>
Prueba esto, que deberia solucionar tu if statement:

function myFunction(){
    if (document.getElementById("radioBtn1").checked) {
        alert('checked');
    } else { 
        alert('not checked');
    }
}); 
</script>


                                        

<input type="submit"  value="Enviar" onClick="myFunction()">
```

Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Cre que el problema es en tu implementacion de jQuery, cuando. invocas `myFunction()` desde el submit, esta funcion declara el `change()` a los inputs pero no la ejecuta.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba esto, que deberia solucionar tu `if` statement:

```javascript
function myFunction(){
    if (document.getElementById("1").checked) {
        alert('checked');
    } else { 
        alert('not checked');
    }
}); 
</script>
```

Te recomiendo usar `id='radioBtn1'` al contrario de `id='1'`

Omiti el uso de `window.open` por que este abre en una nueva ventana del browser.

Comment: Esta respuesta es correcta, pero para que te funcione con el código de la pregunta, debes corregir `function myFuntion(){` ya que el `sumbit` tiene `onClick="myFunction()""` A uno le debes poner `myFunction` (le falta le "c") y el boton tiene unas comillas de más. Quedando asi: `function myFunction(){` y  `onClick="myFunction()"`

Comment: Gracias @Abner no me fije en ese detalle

Comment: Actualice el código, pero sigue sin abrir el popup con el siguiente formulario ...

Comment: Podrías mostrar el codigo de como estas mostrando el formulario en caso de que el radio sea **"SI"**

Comment: Lo estaba haciendo funcionar con windows.open. El problema es que no valida el "si" o "no", solo al llenar el formulario te manda al siguiente formulario, no esta profesional eso, al seleccionar la opción "No", de igual manera te abre el formulario y en esa selección ya no debería. Te dejo el como lo tengo ...

Comment: ´´´´´
<form action="/pre/form.html" >
  <input type="submit" onclick="window.open('pre/form.html','popUpWindow','height=450,width=650,left=100,top=80,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=no');">
</form>
´´´´